# Installing ffmpeg but need to install atrpms first on RedHat 7, issues of 404 not found

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, ffmpeg

I'm following [the instructions given here](http://tecadmin.net/setup-atrpms-repository-on-centos-redhat-and-fedora/) to install the atrpms repository.

After setting everything up and try to do a: `yum install ffmpeg` I get the following error below. The error states that it is a 404 not found. What do you do now?

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager                                                                                                                                                                                               
This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.                                                                                                                 
http://dl.atrpms.net/el7Server-x86_64/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found                                                                                                                                                        
Trying other mirror.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article                                                                                                                                                                                                
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.                                                                                                                                                                        
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 One of the configured repositories failed (Fedora Core 7Server - x86_64 - ATrpms),                                                                                                                                                                                   
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only                                                                                                                                                                                          
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:                                                                                                                                                                                              
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.                                                                                                                                                                                      
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working                                                                                                                                                                                        
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the                                                                                                                                                                                             
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0,0-1         All
     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable atrpms

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=atrpms.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from atrpms: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://dl.atrpms.net/el7Server-x86_64/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the file you created which contains this:

```
[atrpms]
name=Fedora Core $releasever - $basearch - ATrpms
baseurl=http://dl.atrpms.net/f$releasever-$basearch/atrpms/stable
gpgkey=http://ATrpms.net/RPM-GPG-KEY.atrpms
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

Notice the $releasever and $basearch. These need to be filled in with the appropriate information gathered from your server to match the proper links.

If you go straight to the url here: http://dl.atrpms.net/

You'll notice all the version of the linux version its for. But first you need to do this in your system:

**rpm -qa '*release*'**

There you get the correct version you need to input in that link.

Comment: Without knowing much about the subject, [asking this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/334017/73093) right afterwards calls into question how complete or accurate this answer can be taken to be...